# Adding length constraints to line features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, length, constraint

I want to add length constraints to my line feature column 'type' depending on the field value, to make it impossible to create a new line longer than x m.

Below is a screenshot of the categorised 'type' values with the corresponding length constraints I would like to add.

[image]

Is this possible?

I do not use PostGres, this is a private project saved to my desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added a Value field of string type.

Go to Layer Properties - Attributes Form - Drag and drop designer and drag the Value field to Form layout.

Create a Value Map widget type and add the Values you want to be able to choose from.

Check the constraints: "Not null", "Enforce not null", "Enforce expression constraint" and set the expression to:

```
case
    when "Value"='Spine Cable' then $length<=2000
    when "Value"='Distribution Cable' then $length<=2000
    when "Value"='CBT Tail' then $length<=350
    when "Value"='Drop' then $length<=150
end
```

[image]

It will make it impossible to create a line longer than the expression, depending on the Value type:
[image]